# Rendering HTML in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In one of my View (.cshtml) I need to a render a static file (A.html), but at the same time I need to render B.html inside A.html. This is because B.html is a reusable one.

Again, I need to render C.html inside B.html.

I cannot convert the html files to cshtml, in that case I would have use Html.Partial() :(

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Controller.PartialView Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview(v=vs.98).aspx)

Comment: I don't really understand what you trying to do or why you can't use .cshtml. Could you explain it a little clearer.

Comment: Pass A.html to the view as a model property of type string, and then render it as you would any other model property

Comment: Fixed this using CSHTML itself.